# Missing Push Notification Entitlement when update app version

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, appstore-approval

I have an app on appstore and i want to update the app, when i submitted the app for review then i got a mail from apple

as
[image]

My App Did't contain provisioning profile with push configuration.

So Why This error ???

Please help.

Comment: In capabilities did you enabled push notification ?, If no, then switch it on it will generate that. if you don't have push notification requirement switch it off

Comment: Make sure the **Project-->Target-->Capabilities-->Push notifications** is disabled

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya push notification is disabled  Project-->Target-->Capabilities-->Push notifications  .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about publishing to an "app store"  policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)